# Поиск числовых значений

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe7

Функция ищет все числовые значения в строках. Как сделать что бы функция искала только числовые значения длина которых равна = 5.

**То есть строка состоит из:**

```
12345 FC-text212 12345FC-text212
```

**На выходе нужно получить:**

```
12345
12345
```

**Функция:**

```
function StripNonConforming(const S: string;
  const ValidChars: TCharSet): string;
var
  DestI: Integer;
  SourceI: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Result, Length(S));
  DestI := 0;
  for SourceI := 1 to Length(S) do
    if S[SourceI] in ValidChars then
    begin
      Inc(DestI);
      Result[DestI] := S[SourceI]
    end;
  SetLength(Result, DestI)
end;
```

**Пыталась сделать вот так:**

```
if Length(S) = 5 then
```

Но результат не отображается...

**Использую функцию вот так:**

```
Memo2.Text := StripNonConforming(S1, ['0'..'9']);
```

Comment: вам задачу надо решить, или решить с помощью вот этих посимвольных операций? Если решить, то это задача для регулярных выражений.

Comment: @teran, Задачу решить. То есть этой функцией я не получу результат ?

Comment: ваша функция в исходном виде просто копирует все цифры в новую строку. Зачем вы пытаетесь проверить длину S = 5 не ясно. ведь S это входная строка, она явно не длины 5. Есть более подходящие инструменты для решения данной задачи. Ознакомьтесь с принципами построения регулярных выражений, протестируйте их на regex101.com и используйте TRegEx для решения задачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
procedure Extract5Digits(const s: string; res: TStrings);
var
  i: integer;
  start: integer;
begin
  res.Clear;
  start := -1;
  for i := Low(s) to High(s) do
    if (s[i] in ['0'..'9']) then begin
      if start < 0 then
      start := i;
    end else begin
      if (start > 0) and (i - start = 5) then
        res.Add(Copy(s, start, 5));
      start := -1;
    end;
  if (start > 0) and (Length(s) - start = 4) then
        res.Add(Copy(s, start, 5));
end;
```

Comment: А использовать функцию вот так ? Memo2.Text := Extract5Digits(S1);

Comment: Это не функция, а процедура. Результат работы - второй аргумент, в качестве его можно использовать Memo.Lines или другой объект типа TStrings